# Angular 2 | Directives Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to

Tags: angular

I am noob with Angular 2. I am doing YouTube tutorials, but every tutorial have the `directives:` part where i am stuck.

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello</h1><header></header>',
  directives: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

#### The error output is:

```
Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: string; directives: typeof HeaderComponent[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentMetadataType'.at line 6 col 3
```

> header.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({

  selector: 'header',
  template: '<h2>hit!</h2>'

})
export class HeaderComponent { }
```

#### Here's an screenshot of the error [image]

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: which version of angular2 are you using?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`directives` property was removed in **RC.6**

You should move it to `declarations` property of your **NgModule** decorator

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HeaderComponent ], <== here
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: So this worked for me. Does this mean that all components need to be listed in the AppModule now? Doesnt seem very modular if I have to list every module at the global level

Comment: @TommieJones You can split your components into feature module and then import them wherever you want

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please remember to import the component class, and please realize this will be the way to include all dependencies, not just components, but also pipes, etc.

Comment: This is not modular at all. One thing I hate about angular

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **RC6**, then only you should do following,

```
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component' //<----added this line

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,HeaderComponent],                       //<----added HeaderComponent
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: How do I know if I'm using RC6?

Comment: What is RC6, why to use abbreviations while replying to the issue?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common problem faced if you are new to `angular2` and this answer is probably for those who are stuck with the similar kind of problem.

First of all, **don't forget to import the child component class**(here, HeadComponent) in your root component(`app.component.ts`) as follows:-

```
//inside app.component.ts
import{ HeadComponent} from'./components/header/header.component';
```

Then you should move it to declarations in `app.module.ts` follows:-

```
import{ TutorialsComponent} from'./components/header/header.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       AppComponent,HeadComponent]
```

I guess this should help.

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm told me to make the constructor protected. So I did. Caused this problem on a webpack restart. Removing the protected keyword again fixed it.