# Getting template parse errors when attempting to create a new component/directive in angular2-webpack?

Tags: angular

I am using this:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
In this file src/app/home/home.component.ts, I modify it with a new "fancy-button" directive, and include it like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fancy-button',
  template: `<button>clickme</button>`
})
export class FancyButton {}

@Component({
  // The selector is what angular internally uses
  // for `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` in our index.html
  // where, in this case, selector is the string 'home'
  selector: 'home',  // <home></home>
  // We need to tell Angular's Dependency Injection which providers are in our app.
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  // Our list of styles in our component. We may add more to compose many styles together
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ],
  // Every Angular template is first compiled by the browser before Angular runs it's compiler
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  directives: [FancyButton],
})
```

And then inside the template: src/app/home/home.component.html

I added:

```
<fancy-button></fancy-button>
```

I get the error message `main.browser.ts:25Error: Template parse errors:(…)`

When I remove  from the home.component.html, there are no complaints. How do I get around this? I am really not getting why this is complaining...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454379/angular-2-directives-argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to/39454416#39454416

Comment: This seems a little silly, so I have to move FancyButton out to an external file and cannot just add it to the same file as "home.component.ts"? I was thinking of just keeping everything in home.component.ts just for testing. With the answer that that link is proposing, I have to go to my app.module.ts file, import a "fancybutton.component.ts" file, include it in @NgModules, and I have to import it again on home.component.ts to use it... this seems like additional work than just not creating a separate file for it and including it as I have in my post. Is it really not possible todo it easier?

Comment: You have to add this component to decorations array of your module. I don't know where your module

Comment: Its in a separate app.modules.ts directory. Since my FancyButton is in the same file as home.component.ts, when I put FancyButton in the @NgModules, its complaining that it can't find FancyButton... do I have to include the definition of the component in a separate file?

Comment: `import { HomeComponent, FancyButton  }  from './home.component';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following:

```
import { HomeComponent, FancyButton  }  from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent, FancyButton ], <== add this
  bootstrap:    [ HomeComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Also if you click on `(…)` then the full error message is displayes