# angular 2. Cannot insert one component to another. Template parse errors:...is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to repeat actions from tutorial for adding one component inside another but I am failing.

project structure:

[image]

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core"
import {TodoListComponent} from "./todo-list/todo-list.component"

....
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
    directives:[ TodoListComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {
   ...
}
```

app.component.html:

```
...
<todo-list ></todo-list> <!--[todos]="todos"-->
...
```

**todo-list.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core"
//import {Input} from "../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/directives";

@Component({
    selector: "todo-list",
    templateUrl: "./app/todo/todo-list.component.html"
})
export class TodoListComponent {
    //@Input() todos:Todo[];
}
```

**todo-list.component.html**

```
ololololo
```

**Rmain.ts**

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import {AppModule} from "./app.module";

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component"
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

I open browser and see following:

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'todo-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'todo-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'todo-list' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("lass="todo-item" *ngFor="let todo of todos" [ngClass]="{'completed': todo.completed }">-->
        [ERROR ->]<todo-list ></todo-list> <!--[todos]="todos"-->
    </section>
</main>
"): AppComponent@14:8 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
'todo-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'todo-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'todo-list' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("lass="todo-item" *ngFor="let todo of todos" [ngClass]="{'completed': todo.completed }">-->
        [ERROR ->]<todo-list ></todo-list> <!--[todos]="todos"-->
    </section>
</main>
"): AppComponent@14:8
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7728:21)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17503:53)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17423:64)
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17423:21)
    at createResult (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17319:21)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:114:43)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:502:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)consoleError @ zone.js:388_loop_1 @ zone.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
zone.js:390 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:(…)consoleError @ zone.js:390_loop_1 @ zone.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
```

Please point me to the mistake. I rechecked tutorial several times and cannot find mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 RC6: '<component> is not a known element'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333739/angular2-rc6-component-is-not-a-known-element)

Comment: @Joel Almeida I don't see this in tutorial

Comment: how did you declare your module?

Comment: @Joel Almeida If I understood you correct **Rmain.ts** contains this onformation

Comment: Can you please provide your `AppModule` code?

Comment: @Joel Almeida, please see topic update

Comment: Which version angular2 are you using?

Comment: You have to move your directive to `declarations` array of your @NgModule http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454379/angular-2-directives-argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to/39454416#39454416

Comment: @yurzui, Now that error disappered but I see zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/app/todo/todo-list.component.html 404 (Not Found). although if replace **.../app/todo/todo-list...** with **,,,/app/todo-list/todo-list....*** it will work

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503805/zone-js344-unhandled-promise-rejection-failed-to-load-app-template-html-in-ang/39504168#39504168

Comment: @yurzui a lot of thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove  `directives:[ TodoListComponent ]` from `AppComponent` declaration and add declaration of this component to module like this:

```
declarations: [AppComponent, TodoListComponent],
```

Change the Url of todo-list.component.ts to

```
@Component({
    selector: "todo-list",
    templateUrl: "./app/todo-list/todo-list.component.html"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the field 'directives' in app.component.ts and add 'TodoListComponent' in declarations at app.module.ts

your app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component"
import {TodoListComponent} from "./todo-list/todo-list.component"
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TodoListComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```