# Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: string; directives:

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, web

I am learning Angular2, I faced a problem just the same as this guy faced:
[Angular 2 | Directives Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454379/angular-2-directives-argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to)

I followed the way, and I faced another problem, there were 10 errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS1219  (TS) Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.    CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\src\app\movies\movie-list.component.ts 8   Active
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'Iterable'.   CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\default_iterable_differ.d.ts   12  Active
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts   24  Active
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts   32  Active
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'Iterable'.   CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\iterable_differs.d.ts  14  Active
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\keyvalue_differs.d.ts  22  Active
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\di\reflective_provider.d.ts 87  Active
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\src\di\reflective_provider.d.ts 87  Active
Error   TS2585  (TS) 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.d.ts  58  Active
Error   TS2585  (TS) 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.  CrankBank   C:\Demos\CrankBank\ClientApp\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.d.ts  73  Active
```

I am learning it to learn ionic 3 to develop mobile apps, if there are better frames to work with please give your advises.

Comment: It may be better to ask this question as a comment in the solution posted in [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454379/angular-2-directives-argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 | Directives Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454379/angular-2-directives-argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to)