# Error in component.ts file restricts angular from rendering

Tags: angular, angular7

I am just beginning with Angular. When I try to run my angular app, it just shows a blank page and on inspecting it I find the app-root is empty.
So I opened the app.component.ts file and find some error there

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My Angular App';
}
```

Here at the component directive the error says

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrls:
>   string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
>   Property 'true' is missing in type '{ selector: string; templateUrl:
>   string; styleUrls: string[]; }'.

I didnt understand what I did wrong. Angular version 7

Comment: My guess is your cache isn't clean. Close your IDE, delete node_modules, `npm cache clean`, and `npm install` fresh is your best bet from here w/o more info. Other info needed would be the HTML where you have the `<app-root></app-root>` and the `app-root` html itself. Make sure you have all the `imports` in your app-module. Look at the `app-root` HTML and make sure all other components used in it are imported in it's module.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454379/angular-2-directives-argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to)

I think you don't use the correct import, declaretion in app.module.

Comment: But that ts file declaration is autogenerated when I created the application itself. Thats why I am wondering. Angular CLI created the code and it has error?

Comment: @SandeepThomas, No. It's most likely with IDE and `node_modules` in your workspace. Try to install fresh and restart your IDE.

Comment: Sorry since Im a new to Angular.. What are the main things to uninstall? Angular CLI or Node/NPM itself?